# Why implement the productClick event?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I've set up tag manager with enhanced ecommerce on my system. On my category page I use the "impressions" in the dataLayer to measure that the page contains certain products.

1. What is the benefit of measuring "productClick" on traditional links (that the user follows)? Should this not be automatically understand by a tracking tool?
2. Is it not wasteful to rebuild a dataLayer element to track a click when I've already built a dataLayer to track the impressions? Is there a way to simply map a click to the existing impressions data layer? I can see ways to do this using js but since it seems wasteful to rebuild the same data again, I thought there might already be solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a design decision by Google. They don't necessarily know that your link is associated with a product.
2. You can use the same object for the click as you do for the impression. In most architectures you can fire the impression and attach an event handler to the link in the same place of your code.

If you don't like to repeat yourself you can always aim for a declarative implementation where you add `data-` attributes to your links in the HTML/DOM. Then have a central Javascript which parses these data attributes, fires impressions and adds onClick handlers.